# Python tag based syntax highlighting

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, syntax-highlighting

Currently the [python](/questions/tagged/python) tag sets syntax highlighting to python, but the [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7) tag does not. Should this be the case?